# How to hit a url to get response via curl requests in chunks

Tags: php, httprequest, httpwebrequest, php-curl

Hi i am working on a project that requires hitting a url against each id stored in an array using curl.the response of each request is then further used to perform some calculations.The only issue i am facing is that the size of the array is huge i.e approx 25000 so basically i have to make around 25000 curl requests,which is i think is not feasible so i was hoping is there anyway i can divide the array into smaller chunks,and hit the url chunk by chunk

```
  $array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10........25000];
  $chunk1=[1,2,...1000];
  $chunk2=[1000,1001....2000];
```

**and So on**

Comment: this totally depends on the consuming url you are 'hitting', right? A normal way would be `?ids[]=1&ids[]=2` or send the ids in the POST data.

Comment: @Jeff sir i have to do it using get request i am making 25000 urls using loop from 0 to 24999 and the sample url is abc.com?q=1 and so on

Comment: then do it that way `?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&...`

Comment: @Jeff without breaking the array into chunks i tried implementing it using multi_curl to send requests synchronously but it worked fine only for 200 request and after that my program crashed

Comment: @Jeff you meant i pass each id as an array in query string parameter

Comment: yes. well, technically its an array of ids (and will land as array in `$_GET['ids']` - but I don't know what your backend is)

Comment: @Jeff sir the url i want to hit is an api which doesn’t accept an array as a parameter but simple one variable per request per request my question is how can i hit urls concurrently to get the response of all 25000 requests successfully

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this will help to solve your requirement

```
    <?php
    $input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'); //  $array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10........25000];

    print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2)); //In your case $arraychunk=array(); $arraychunk=array_chunk($array,1000); you will find the chunked array ranging from $arraychunk[0] to $arraychunk[24] each of thousand values
    print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2, true)); //In your case $arraychunk=array(); $arraychunk=array_chunk($array,1000,true); you will find the chunked array ranging from $arraychunk[0] to $arraychunk[24] each of thousand values here it preserves keys
    ?>


    //output

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => c
                [1] => d
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => e
            )

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [2] => c
                [3] => d
            )

        [2] => Array
            (    
                [4] => e
            )

    )



     //You may use curl like this
        <?php 

    function fun($id){
    // create curl resource 
    $url='http://example.com?id=$id';
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);    

    }

    //similarly for all chunked arrays
    foreach($arraychunk[0] as $key=>$value)  {

        $values=$value;
        func($values);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: And now should i write recursive function to hit urls using these chunked arrays?

Comment: call your function in foreach loop for each value & pass it as id in url

Comment: @Iqra Raees check now in the post i have added some basic curl function & how to call that function also

Comment: Sir i will definitely try it and get back to u as soon as it give error

Comment: Sir i have an issue

Comment: @Iqra Rahees can you please let me know what issue you have?